# redirect dosen't works in codelgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am using codelgniter and i want to pass the below 3 parameters to site_url().But this take only the method name not the parameters.... How can i pass these parameters. Please help me

```
   function report_del() {

    $island = $this->tables($this->input->post('island'));

    $prefix = $this->tables($this->input->post('prefix'));

    $date = $this->tables($this->input->post('date'));


    redirect(site_url('admin/admin/dateandprefix/').$date.'/'.$prefix.'/'.$island);

    //$segments = array('admin/admin/dateandprefix/',$date,$prefix,$island);
    //redirect(site_url($segments));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is copy pasted, there is an error in the single quote

```
redirect(site_url('admin/admin/dateandprefix/').$date.'/'.$prefix.'/'.$island);
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't get parameters and show the below error Message: Missing argument 1 for Admin::dateandprefix() Message: Missing argument 2 for Admin::dateandprefix() Message: Missing argument 3 for Admin::dateandprefix()

Comment: well, the question then is answered. you may open a new one to find out what's going on with the parameters

Answer (score 1):

you are making a mistake . use site url like this .

```
redirect(site_url('admin/admin/dateandprefix/'.$date.'/'.$prefix.'/'.$island));
```

for more details you can view this link
[user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
redirect('admin/admin/dateandprefix/'.$date.'/'.$prefix.''.$island.'','refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI4
Then use in base use and/public after that
http://localhost/foldername/public
then it work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).